# Не работает дебаг в связке PHPStorm + xdebug

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

Xdebug настроен. Стоит xdebug helper. Валидация в PHPStorm проходит нормально

При запуске сессии с включенным  "Breake at first line ..." происходит остановка на первой строке index.php - она пустая, но останавливает. 
[image: Остановка на пустой строке]
Дальше по F8 ни происходит ничего. В браузере висит "Ожидание localdomain". Если отключить телефонную трубку в Storm'e, то страница сразу загружается. Как будто что-то где-то ждет выполнения, но не может законнектиться.

Конфиг дебага

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="%sprogdir%/modules/php/%phpdriver%/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.auto_trace = 0
xdebug.collect_includes = 1
;xdebug.collect_params = 4
;xdebug.collect_return = 1
;xdebug.collect_assignments = 1
;xdebug.collect_vars = 1
xdebug.dump.REQUEST = *
xdebug.dump.SESSION = *
xdebug.dump.SERVER = REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD
;xdebug.dump.COOKIE =
;xdebug.dump.FILES =
;xdebug.dump.GET =
;xdebug.dump.POST =
xdebug.dump_globals = 1
xdebug.dump_once = 1
xdebug.dump_undefined = 1
xdebug.extended_info = 1
;xdebug.file_link_format = ""
xdebug.idekey = "PHPStorm"
;xdebug.manual_url = "http://www.php.net"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 256
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1
;xdebug.profiler_append = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/xdebug/"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%H%R"
;xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
;xdebug.remote_log = ""
;xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
;xdebug.scream = 1
;xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
;xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
;xdebug.show_mem_delta = 1
;xdebug.trace_format = 1
;xdebug.trace_options = 1
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "%sprogdir%/userdata/temp/xdebug/"
;xdebug.trace_output_name = "trace.%H%R"
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 256
;xdebug.var_display_max_data = 1024
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 16
;xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 3600
```

OpenServer 5.2.2, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.1x64, Win7.

Если убрать "Breake at first line ...", то не происходит вообще ничего. Пустая страница и "ожидание соединения"

Comment: PHPStorm значение из xdebug.idekey установили в XDebug helper (там по умолчанию XDEBUG_SESSION_START для PHPStorm IDE)? В PhpStorm сделали настройку на этот ключ в IDE session key? Смотрите скрин https://imgur.com/a/zfqztm5 для настройки сервера.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov не, оказался конфликт версий шторма и Хдебага.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153944/phpstorm-xdebug-connection-established-no-debug-window-popup-in-phpstorm) 
Версия PHPStorm 2018.1.4 конфликтует с xdebug 2.7.

После обновления шторма до 2018.3.4 все завелось с пол-оборота.